# How to access arrays within an object with JNI?

Tags: java-native-interface

JNI tutorials, for instance [this](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/) one, cover quite well how to access primitive fields within an object, as well as how to access arrays that are provided as explicit function arguments (i.e. as subclasses of `jarray`). But how to access Java (primitive) arrays that are fields *within* an `jobject`? For instance, I'd like to operate on the byte array of the following Java object:

```java
class JavaClass {
  ...
  int i;
  byte[] a;
}
```

The main program could be something like this:

```java
class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JavaClass jc = new JavaClass();
    jc.a = new byte[100];
    ...
    process(jc);
  }

  public static native void process(JavaClass jc);
}
```

The corresponding C++ side would then be:

```cpp
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Test_process(JNIEnv * env, jclass c, jobject jc) {

  jclass jcClass = env->GetObjectClass(jc);
  jfieldID iId = env->GetFieldID(jcClass, "i", "I");

  // This way we can get and set the "i" field. Let's double it:
  jint i = env->GetIntField(jc, iId);
  env->SetIntField(jc, iId, i * 2);

  // The jfieldID of the "a" field (byte array) can be got like this:
  jfieldID aId = env->GetFieldID(jcClass, "a", "[B");

  // But how do we operate on the array???
}
```

I was thinking to use `GetByteArrayElements`, but it wants an `ArrayType` as its argument. Obviously I'm missing something. Is there a way to to this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I hope that will help you a little (check out the [JNI Struct reference](http://xdprof.sourceforge.net/doxygen/structJNIEnv__.html), too):

```cpp
// Get the class
jclass mvclass = env->GetObjectClass( *cls );
// Get method ID for method getSomeDoubleArray that returns a double array
jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID( mvclass, "getSomeDoubleArray", "()[D");
// Call the method, returns JObject (because Array is instance of Object)
jobject mvdata = env->CallObjectMethod( *base, mid);
// Cast it to a jdoublearray
jdoubleArray * arr = reinterpret_cast<jdoubleArray*>(&mvdata)
// Get the elements (you probably have to fetch the length of the array as well
double * data = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(*arr, NULL);
// Don't forget to release it 
env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(*arr, data, 0);
```

Ok here I operate with a method instead of a field (I considered calling a Java getter cleaner) but you probably can rewrite it for the fields as well. Don't forget to release and as in the comment you'll probably still need to get the length.

Edit: Rewrite of your example to get it for a field. Basically replace CallObjectMethod by GetObjectField.

```cpp
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Test_process(JNIEnv * env, jclass c, jobject jc) {

  jclass jcClass = env->GetObjectClass(jc);
  jfieldID iId = env->GetFieldID(jcClass, "i", "I");

  // This way we can get and set the "i" field. Let's double it:
  jint i = env->GetIntField(jc, iId);
  env->SetIntField(jc, iId, i * 2);

  // The jfieldID of the "a" field (byte array) can be got like this:
  jfieldID aId = env->GetFieldID(jcClass, "a", "[B");

  // Get the object field, returns JObject (because Array is instance of Object)
  jobject mvdata = env->GetObjectField (jc, aID);

  // Cast it to a jdoublearray
  jdoubleArray * arr = reinterpret_cast<jdoubleArray*>(&mvdata)

  // Get the elements (you probably have to fetch the length of the array as well  
  double * data = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(*arr, NULL);

  // Don't forget to release it 
  env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(*arr, data, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks; it's clever (and maybe even cleaner) to use getters. I'll have to do it this way unless someone points how to directly get the array fields, in GetXXXField-like fashion.

Comment: Ok I added you example for the field (basically just use GetObjectField instead of CallObjectMethod). Though I can of course not guarantee that it'll run out of the box I hope you can get the general idea :)

Comment: Right! Somehow I was expecting to find a bit more straightforward way to do this, and so I was reluctant to go back to definitions ("array is an object" :-) Programming psychology... Thanks again!

Comment: I also saw the same in other answers. Why `double * data`? Why not `jdouble * data`?

Comment: why use reinterpret_cast instead of static cast?

Comment: Old question, but @Andros a static_cast forbids conversion from jobject* --> jdoubleArray* although jdoublearray is inherited from jobject as @ this [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libnativehelper/+/master/include/nativehelper/jni.h#50)

Answer (score 7):

In gcc 6.3 I get a warning saying "dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules" from a line like this:

```
jdoubleArray arr = *reinterpret_cast<jdoubleArray*>(&mvdata);
```

But since jdoubleArray is itself a pointer to class _jdoubleArray, there's no need to get the address before casting, and this static_cast works without warnings:

```
jdoubleArray arr = static_cast<jdoubleArray>(mvdata);
```