# JNI: how to return byte array via java field?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, arrays

I have a Java object and a byte[] field in it like this:

```
class MyJavaClass {
public byte[] mData;
}
```

On JNI side I have a byte array like this:

```
unit8_t* bytes;
int size;
```

I can access this `mData` object from JNI but I don't know what to do on JNI side so that this `mData` object has those bytes in it.

I can't allocate a `jByteArray` every time because  the data change quite often. So I just want to set `mData` from JNI and then I'll inform Java via some other callback that I've set up the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to access arrays within an object with JNI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086596/how-to-access-arrays-within-an-object-with-jni).

Comment: Yes, mine is a dup, I'll be removing it shortly

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to emulate array with native methods:

`public native byte array_get(int idx)`, `public native byte array_set(int idx, byte value)`?

Comment: Because I'm then passing that array in its entirety to some 3rd party API