# jni struct from java to C

Tags: arrays, struct, java-native-interface

I have one problem. In java I have a class like

```
public class s_k {
    public byte[][] s;
    public int r;
}
```

in C correspondingly a structure,

```
typedef struct {
  unsigned char s[10][10];
  int r;
} s_k;
```

and have one function from  which java passes this as a parameter type of s_k.
How to get it in C code and change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point in making a structure reflection of your Java class. It will be a **copy** of your Java class, which means that changing it won't change your original Java object. I suppose you do want the changes to be reflected in the original object, right?

So simply pass the `s_k` instance as `jobject` and access it directly with powers of JNI:

- **r** with `GetFieldID` and then `SetIntField`
- **s** again with `GetFieldID`, then `GetObjectField` (array is an object in Java) and then `GetByteArrayElements`

There is not a simpler way, unless you want to dive into [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna#readme).

**UPDATE:** there seems to be a duplicate of your question:

[How to access arrays within an object with JNI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086596/how-to-access-arrays-within-an-object-with-jni)

Comment: about r everything is ok ! GetObjectClass then GetFieldID then GetIntField. but i have difficulties with s. GetObjectClass then GetFieldID then GetObjectField and GetByteArrayRegion but it gives me some other data. what can be wrong with this steps ?

Comment: Simplify your data to prove the problem. Make it one dimensional array and use `GetByteArrayElements` to fetch whole array in a simple way. It simply cannot be "some other data". If the problem persists, fill a new question with specific code snippet. Keep your questions focused.