# JNI Accessing Object Array

Tags: java, c++, arrays, java-native-interface

I'm currently learning JNI and I'm stucked (for two days) with this problem. I have an Object that has an char array and I want to manipulate it with C and JNI.

My code is:

```
public class ImageWrapper
{
    private int[] imagem;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    public ImageWrapper()
    {
        getImage();
    }


    private native void getImage();
}
```

in c++ is as folowing:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_jnisample_ImageWrapper_getImage(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj)
{
    //Get the class object
    jclass thisClass = env->GetObjectClass(thisObj);

    //Get the width variable and set it to 100
    jfieldID idWidth = env->GetFieldID(thisClass, "width", "I");
    env->SetIntField(thisObj, idWidth, 100);

    //Get the height variable and set it to 100
    jfieldID idHeight = env->GetFieldID(thisClass, "height", "I");
    env->SetIntField(thisObj, idHeight, image.size().height);

    int*data = new int[100*100];
    for(int i=0; i< 100*100; i++)
         data[i] = i;

    //How do I set the imagem array in Java to be filled with the data I created here?
    return;
}
```

My question is how I manipulate it and how do I save any changes?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086596/how-to-access-arrays-within-an-object-with-jni?rq=1

Comment: I tried to follow that and it didn't work (or I didn't understand it)

Comment: Your code will NEVER work. `char` in Java is 2 bytes. In C++, it is 1 byte. Thus your Java `char` array should be a `byte` array. Even better, a `java.nio.ByteBuffer`.

Comment: Changed it to Int. Now how do I do it?